# MongoDB use another query if the first query has no results

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query a field in my MongoDB with operator `$all`, but if there's no results found, I would like to query it again with operator `$in`

Here's what did I do now

```
var q = Query.All("Field", new BsonArray(listRegexSearch));
var results = collection.Find(q).ToList();
if (results.Count() == 0 || results == null) {
    q = Query.In("Field", new BsonArray(listRegexSearch))
    results = collection.Find(q).ToList();
}
foreach(var res in results) {
    ... // Code to process the results
}
```

Are there anyway that I could achieve it in one query without using the if statement like what I do now

Comment: You only want to do the second query if the first has 0 results, so it wouldn't be ok to `$or` the queries together? If that is the case, then you must do two queries after checking that the first had no results.

Comment: @wdberkeley, so there's no other way than do the second query after check if the first one return 0 results or null?

Comment: That depends on the answer to me question in my first comment.